# How to use ServiceStack Logging but have it delivered through the IOC container

Tags: asp.net, servicestack

Title about sums up what I'm looking to achieve, although now that I'm posting some code I would also like to know if the LogFactory in the correct place.

Thank you,
Stephen

```
public class ContactAppHost : AppHostBase
{
    //Tell Service Stack the name of your application and where to find your web services
    public ContactAppHost() : base("Contact Web Services", typeof (ContactService).Assembly)
    {
        // Built into the framework without the IOC
        LogManager.LogFactory = new NLogFactory();
    }

    public override void Configure(Funq.Container container)
    {
        //register any dependencies your services use, e.g:
        container.Register<ICacheClient>(new MemoryCacheClient());
    }
}


protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    new ContactAppHost().Init();
}

protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ServiceStack only supports the configuration of a single logger which should ideally be specified before the AppHost is initialized, so all static `ILog` initalizers for all classes in ServiceStack use the configured logger, e.g:

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LogManager.LogFactory = new NLogFactory();
    new ContactAppHost().Init();
}
```

Comment: OK, on where to do the init of the logger, but what about the IOC container delivering it to an ILog property elsewhere?

Comment: @StephenPatten we only use static initializers so we never inject it into the IOC ourselves.